# mongoimport error: Unexpected identifier

Tags: mongodb

When I try to import my json data file into my local instance of mongodb, I get an error. The code that I am using is shown below.

```
> mongoimport --db cities --collection zips --type json --file C:/MongoDB/data/zips.json
```

This is the error that I get.

2014-11-29T20:27:33.803-0800 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

what seems to be to problem here?

Comment: Could be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243888

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that `mongoimport` is used from terminal/command line(cmd), and NOT within the mongo shell.